# form with no form_id(Drupal 6.x)

Tags: forms, drupal-6

I have this form placed inside a block and it is assigned to right region of my site. Form is displayed just fine. But the submit button doesn't work as intended - to call submit function. So, I did some debugging and found an anomaly that there is no essential data - such as form_id and tokens - drupal normally injected to every form. As I can't figure out the root cause of this, I'm here for pointers of friends from here. Here's an excerpt of my code -

```
function mymodule_block($op = 'list', $delta = '', $edit = array()) {

switch ($op) {
    case 'list':
        $blocks['quick_search'] = array(
            'info'       => t('Quick Search'),

        );
    return $blocks; 

    case 'view':
        switch ($delta) {
            case 'quick_search':
                $block['subject'] = t('Quick Search');
                $block['content'] = drupal_get_form("block_quick_search");
            break;        
        }

    return $block;
}


}


function block_quick_search(&$form_state){
$form = array();
.
.
.
    $form['quick_search_submit'] = array(
        '#type' => 'submit',
        '#value' => t('Search'),        
        '#submit' => array('mymodule_quick_search'),
    );                              

    return $form;   

}

function mymodule_quick_search($form, &$form_state){

drupal_goto($base_path,"..............");   
}
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> there is no essential data - such as form_id and tokens

This is indeed the reason why form submissions are not processed correctly. Check whether [drupal_prepare_form](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--form.inc/function/drupal_prepare_form/6) is called on your form and whether it adds those items correctly. It is called by [drupal_get_form](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--form.inc/function/drupal_get_form/6) if he form is not posted (and thusly not retrieved from the cache).

If `$form['#token']` and `$form['form_id']` are added correctly, I suspect something is wrong with translating the form to HTML. Do you use any custom theming for the form?

Comment: Your question of custom theming reminds me of I have given too much focused on positioning individual elements in my custom template. So, I went back and check my template if I render the rest of elements with drupal_render;voila, I didn't. That's is why. Thanks a lot for pointing that out.

Answer (score 0):

Try to pass your submit handler to the main form and not on the item submit like that:

```
$form['#submit'][] = 'mymodule_quick_search';
```

it should work.